# How to connect to a Windows server on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, windows, file-server

At work I usually run Windows 8 but I'm looking to use Linux since I'm mostly a Linux user. How do I connect to it usually? I just type `//MIKE-SERVER` then hit ENTER key in address bar of a file browser. How would I do that on Linux? It's a Windows Server.

Answer (score 3):

To connect to your share using CLI interface, you need to install smbclient (Samba client). Then you can access your windows machine like the following:

```
smbclient //MIKE-SERVER -U <your_windows_credentials>
```

and you will be prompted for a password.

Answer (score 0):

It varies depending on your file browser you're using. Here I'm using Cinnamon's file browser, Nemo, which has a pulldown called "Connect to server". Most of the browsers have something similar.

[image: ss1]

[image: ss2]

You can put your server, share, and credentials in this dialog to connect to a remote server's share.